# Listserv type software to replace Yahoo! Groups

Tags: linux, web-apps, email, forum, mailing-list

I currently help run a large (14k+) Yahoo! group and the general consensus is that yahoo is simply becoming too much to put up with.  However rather than just switching to yet another group like Google Groups -

I would like to just find some sort of discussion list software and use that in conjunction with the groups website (Currently built using [Joomla!](http://joomla.org), though I don't mind rebuilding it if needed).  Oh - I am using [A Small Orange](http://asmallorange.com/) as my web host, they are not particularly restrictive on what you can run within reason, but it is not a dedicated server - though I may upgrade to that at some point.

Anyway - suggestions for replacing Yahoo! Groups greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla has a robust message board module called [Kunena](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum/7256). You can read a lot about the module on the [Kunena homepage](http://www.kunena.org/) as well.

Kunena can mimic a listserv reasonably well if that's the primary goal. Users can be manually or automatically "subscribed" to certain posts or entire topics. Once subscribed, users will get pinged with e-mails when there is new activity. This [auto-subscription extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/kunena-forum-extensions/22778) for Kunena might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Our local club also has used Yahoo Groups for many years.

We have made the switch to [Mailster](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/marketing/mailing-a-distribution-lists/mailster) three years ago, which is a discussion list plugin for Joomla. That allows for the two-communication over email.

There is also a WordPress version, called [WP Mailster](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mailster), available.